# Let $ X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda =1), Y\sim U(1,2) $ be independent continuous variables. What is $E(\frac{x}{y})$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I'm struggling to understand how to start the following:

> Let $  X \sim  \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda =1), Y\sim U(1,2) $ be independent
>   continuous variables. What is $E(\frac{x}{y})$?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(\frac X Y |Y)=\frac 1 Y EX=\frac 1 Y$. Taking expectation we get $E\frac X Y=E\frac 1 Y=\int_1^{2} \frac 1 y \, dy=\ln\, 2$.

Comment: Note that this only holds because $Y$ is never zero and thus the division expression is well-defined.

Comment: Thanks, but why is the condition taking place? ($E(\frac{X}{Y} | Y) $?

Comment: @superuser123 You can also do this using a double integral but using conditional expectation makes it easier.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy how could it be done by a double integral? thanks!

Comment: @superuser123 Calculate (by integrating w.r.t  $x$ and then w.r.t. $y$ or the other way around)  $\int_0^{\infty} \int_1^{2} \frac x y e^{-x} \,dy\, dx$

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then so are $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ where $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions.

Consequence for expectation (if it exists):$$\mathbb Ef(X)g(Y)=\mathbb Ef(X)\mathbb Eg(Y)$$

This can be applied to find: $$\mathbb E[XY^{-1}]=\mathbb EX\mathbb EY^{-1}$$
It only remains now to find $\mathbb EX$ and $\mathbb EY^{-1}$.